# How to periodically save location updates using async task?

Tags: android

Currently I am trying to collect location updates periodically, say for every 10 samples. I am using an arraylist to collect them and clear off the arraylist in the main UI thread once I passed them to the server using async task. In the async task I am loading the arraylist with the one from main UI.

The problem is, it is clearing the arraylist in the async task even it is in separate variable. How can I keep the activity in sync. Do I need to sleep the main activity till the async task finishes. I am not sure about the variable. Can someone explain how to do this?

```
MainMapActivity(X){
  locationupdate for every 1 min{
  arraylist a;//this collects all location updates 10 samples each time
  call asynctask b;
  clear a;
}
asynctask b{
  arraylist c = getall from  a;
  db= insert(c);//save a into database;
}
```

Clearing a in main UI clears of variable c. How can I prevent that? The variable c should be only cleared after saving all the data in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting what you are trying to say is,then yes, we have a way to fix your problem using handlers.

In your async task, do something like this -

```
   private mLocations;
 public MyTask(Handler mResponseHandler, List<Location> mLocations){
        super();
        this.mLocations = mLocations;
        this.mResponseHandler = mResponseHandler;
    }
```

in onPostExecute,

```
  onPostExecute(List<Location>){

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.i(TAG, "result = "+result);
        if (mResponseHandler == null) return;

        MyLocationData<Location> resultData = new MyLocationData<Location>();
        if(result != null && result){
            resultData.requestSuccessful = true;
            resultData.responseErrorCode = 0;
        }else{
            resultData.requestSuccessful = false;
            resultData.responseErrorCode = errorCode;  //set this when result is null
        }

        android.os.Message m = android.os.Message.obtain();
        m.obj = resultData;
        mResponseHandler.sendMessage(m);
    }
}
```

Where MyLocationData is a model class in which I'm saving all relevant data. It can be a class like this -

```
 public class MyLocationData<Type> {

    public Type response;
    public int responseErrorCode;
    public boolean requestSuccessful;
}
```

Now, in your activity, you can get this data like,

```
private Handler mExportHandler = new Handler(){ 

        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                MyLocationData<Location> responseData = (MyLocationData<Location>) msg.obj;
                 // your logic for fetching new locations from responseData and using them in your activity   

        };
    };
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik. Thanks for that. But I am not so sure about the code you provided me. Can you please be specific with the sample code I am updating to the question.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what you are not getting in the solution. This solution is getting your data from asyncTask and then with the help of a handler, you are using it in your activity.

Comment: actually I am new to java and android. So, I am not clear with handlers concept. So, I tried to ask you if you could explain me with the algorithm I stated above. For now I am able to avoid it by making a sleep(2000) in the main UI which I think is wrong way of doing it.

Comment: Actually, Object References tell a way to reach that object in memory, but they do not contain the actual object value. So, you may have two references for same object, and when you are clearing a, it's clearing c, because both are referring to same list object on memory. So either you can create two different objects having same value or you can clear the list inside your async task.

}
asynctask b{
  arraylist c = getall from  a;
  db= insert(c);//save a into database;
clear a;
}

Comment: I can't clear a inside async task because I need to start collecting new location values into that after passing the existing bundle to async task. So, any suggestions

Comment: Then create two different Objects as suggested in last post